# Fixing unescaped # in the URL with nginx

Tags: nginx, escaping, uri-fragment

A bad HTTP client isn't escaping hash signs and is sending them to nginx, like so:

```
GET /foo/escaped#stuff
```

Instead of:

```
GET /foo/escaped%23stuff
```

This breaks my nginx configuration, since nginx strips the text after the `#` in the `proxy_pass` directive. How do I escape the hash sign?

- Using `return 200 "$request_uri";` does show me that nginx is reading it, so it seems like it's possible. Nginx, however, ignores it in `location` blocks, so I can't actually match it with anything.
- You can use the below code to send unescaped HTTP GET requests in Python:

  ```
  import socket

  def get(host, port, uri):
      sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      sock.connect((host, port))
      sock.send('GET {} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {}\r\n\r\n'.format(uri, host))

      return sock.recv(1000)
  ```

Comment: You probably should fix that client.  Not escaping `#` is pretty bad.  You will never be able to match it with `location` because `/a#b` *is* the same location as `/a#c`. Still, [see the previous question about hash-bangs in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380108/nginx-hashbang-rewrite)

Comment: @grochmal: Nothing I can do about the client, unfortunately. If I could fix it, I would.